# Is there a way to have a notes section on a site and have those notes be saved to the document set?

Tags: 2013, workflow, content-type

We are trying to automate our funding process and we need a section where the employees can take notes for when they make their phone calls and verification. I have been trying to work with the document set content type and the activity feed, as well as the note board functions.

The image I am trying to create is document set with all the important documents in it, with an activity feed on the right side of the page specific to that document set and a notes section on the bottom of the page. But the notes will have to be saved to that document set, and they will have to stay with that document set.

Is this something that can be created using pre-existing components or is this something that will need to be written?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have OneNote, you could use a shared OneNote notebook that is part of the document set to track the comments.